# Show that 3 is the most efficient number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Given a constant $n$, construct a sequence of natural numbers $a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_k$ such that:

- $a_0 + a_1 + \cdots + a_k \leq n$
- $a_0 a_1 \cdots a_k$ is maximized

I conjecture that the solution is as follows:

Add $3$ to your sequence. Subtract $3$ from $n$. Repeat until the leftover is $2, 3, \text{or } 4$. If the leftover is $2$, end your sequence with a $2$; if the leftover is $3$, end your sequence with a $3$; and if the leftover is $4$, end your sequence with two $2$s.

To show this, I want to say that $3$ is the most digit-efficient number.

For all natural numbers $m > 1$, we can say:

$$3^m \geq m^3$$

Both the LHS and RHS of this inequality have a sequence sum of $3m$.

Is this enough to show that my solution is correct? I have a strong feeling that my proof is missing something (for example, the odd case of a leftover of $4$ isn't really "explained"), but I'm not sure what. How can I formalize what I've written, and what do I need to add to make it a comprehensive solution?

---

Just to clear up any questions about what this problem is asking, let's say $n = 11$. Then:

$$3+3+3+2 = 11$$
$$3*3*3*2 = 54$$

And $54$ is the highest number you can make. Here, the sequence in question is $\{3, 3, 3, 2\}$.

Comment: Are the $a_i$ required to be integers?

Comment: Natural numbers, yep. Let me edit the original post with that - good catch! Though, I'm curious what the answer is if we relax that constraint.

Comment: $4^m\geq m^4$ and both sides sum to $4m$, so if that was enough, $4$ would be as good as $3$.

Comment: @Henrik That's not true in the case of $m=3$, which is why I thought maybe my statement had some weight to it.

Comment: I have a feeling that without requiring the $a_i$'s to be natural numbers, optimum would be reached for $a_i=e$ (with some remainder).

Comment: That is also what I started thinking about, but then I remembered I don't know how to formalize the simpler case, so I shouldn't get too ahead of myself. (Maybe something like subtract out $e$ until your leftover is as close to $1$ without going under.) :P

Comment: @Henrik in fact it is.  I remember solving a special case of this question in the case that $n=100$.  Once analytically, and a second time via brute force (did it in java, needing to call `bignumber`).  The analytical solution is indeed that $3$ is the natural number closest to $e$ and the product is maximized when all terms are as close to $e$ as possible.

Comment: SSS: RIght, that argument has problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is $a_i\gt4$, we have

$$
2(a_i-2)=2a_i-4\gt a_i\;,
$$

contradicting optimality. Thus $a_i\le4$ for all $i$. We can replace any $4$ by two $2$s without changing the constraint or the objective function. Also $1$s are obviously suboptimal.

Thus all $a_i$ are either $2$ or $3$. Any group of three $2$s can be improved on by replacing it by two $3$s. Since two $2$s are better than one $3$, it follows that the optimal solution is the one consisting of all $3$s and the unique number of zero to two $2$s to make the sum equal $n$.

Note the connection to the Fast Fourier Transform, where this optimization problem arises in the choice of the radix. The radix $3$ is optimal in this sense, but the more usual radix $2$ has other advantages.

To motivate the solution using calculus, we can divide $n$ into $k$ equal parts and maximize $\left(\frac nk\right)^k$ with respect to $k$:

$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dk}\log\left(\frac nk\right)^k=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dk}\left(k(\log n-\log k)\right)=\log n-\log k-1\stackrel{!}{=}0\;,
$$

yielding $k=\frac n{\mathrm e}$ and thus parts of size $\mathrm e$. The optimal value of$ \left(\frac nk\right)^k$ is thus

$$
\left(\sqrt[\mathrm e]{\mathrm e}\right)^n\approx1.445^n\;,
$$

compared with

$$
\left(\sqrt[2]2\right)^n\approx1.414^n
$$

and

$$
\left(\sqrt[3]3\right)^n\approx1.442^n\;,
$$

so the differences between $2$, $\mathrm e$ and $3$ are rather marginal.